# Laravel 5.2 Auth and Password route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I saw that Laravel 5.2 change the `routes.php` use.

In fact, the old :

```
Route::controllers([
'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

don't work now.

Instead I saw it was better to use :

```
Route::Auth();
```

But this method don't provide password and register route like it use to...

Actually, I use a solution I saw on Stack Overflow, using get and post method :

```
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
[...]

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
[...]

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset/{token?}','Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
[...]
```

It's quite awful, so is there a better usage of the 5.2 route.php file for this new Laravel version ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What does it mean "don't work now" for you ? What exactly doesn't work? What steps are you doing ?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek
I just edited my post. I hope i'm clear ...
Laravel just don't understand my Route::controllers() method. Also, i'm trying to use 5.1 method on the new 5.2 version, that's quite a bad idea maybe...

Comment: @Jiedara Are you migrating from 5.1 to 5.2?

Comment: @Bogdan
No, i'm just trying the Laravel 5.2 to see the new adds of the version :)
But I don't get why the route:controllers() method vanished or how to use it well again ... Maybe I'm just using it wrong...

Comment: The `Route::controllers(...)` method didn't vanish, it's [still there](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L227-L232). Also if you're using 5.2 just run `php artisan auth:make` and let Laravel take care of [setting up](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#included-routing) it's authentication resources. `Route::auth()` will generate [these routes](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L346-L361).

Comment: @Bogdan

Wow, that's impressive ! 

So now, Laravel can generate these route automatically. That's great !

Thanks for your help ! I'll be happy to validate your answer if you post it :)

Comment: @Jiedara keep in mind that `Route::controller` has been deprecated. It will be removed in Laravel 5.3 (due June 2016). So it's best if you find a different way to do it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Laravel 5.2, the authentication system is much easier to get up and running. You can simply run this command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

That will take care of setting up the necessary authentication resources: route definitions, views, etc. There's more info on the subject in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#included-routing). You can also check out [this article](https://laravel-news.com/2015/12/laravel-5-2-is-released/) to see other features that are new to Laravel 5.2.

Answer (score 3):

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php
go for this file auth method, there all routes defined

Answer (score 2):

May This Code Help You..

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
Route::get('auth/confirm/{token}', 'Auth\AuthController@getConfirm');
```

For Password

```
  Route::get('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
  Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');


  Route::get('password/reset{token}','Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
  Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
```

Comment: But that's what I already make.
I wonder if there is a better way to do that, just like the route:controller().
If not, thanks, you got the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have some trouble to access /login and /register with the new authentication system. You should look at the [session documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session).

The way (or some parts) of storing sessions is changed. You have to setup a session table. How you can do this will be explained in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias Route:

```
Route::get('auth/login', ['as'=>'getLogin', 'uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm'];
Route::post('auth/login', ['as'=>'postLogin', 'uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@postLogin'];
```

In Controller create public function:

```
public function showLoginForm() {
    return view('auth.login');
}

public function postLogin(Request $data) {
    $users = new User();
    $users->username = $data->txtUsername;
    ...
}
```